# Segmentation fault when trying to copy command line arguments in an integer array

Tags: c

Iam trying to read command line arguments and store them into an array of integers. When I compile the code I do not get any errors. When I run the code I get - Segmentation Fault core dumped. What might be the issue?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    int N = argc;
    int i = 0;
    int a[N];

    printf("\n Number of arguments: %d", argc);

    if(argc>1){
        for(i = 0;i<argc;i++){
            a[i] = atoi(argv[i+1]);  //read variables from command line to a[i]
        }
    }
    else {
        printf("\n Insufficient Arguments.... Exit()");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("\n The values stored in the array are: ");
    for(i = 0;i<argc-1;i++){
        printf("\n %d",a[i]);  //print values
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you add 1 to i you will always read 1 too many arguments. you wanted `for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) { a[i] = atoi(argv[i]); }`

Comment: What did your debugger say where the crash was?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It would appear that you need to learn how to use a debugger to step line-by-line through your code, which will likely allow you to easily pinpoint the nature and location of the issue you're having. Using a debugger is, for all intents and purposes, required knowledge for any programmer. For more info, see [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: @LambdaBeta but argv[0] is the name of the executable i.e ./exe isn't it? So I must start copying from argv[1] till argv[argc-1].

Comment: Thankyou @melpomene yes you are right! But Iam yet to learn gdb

Comment: @RandomDavis that was helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you're walking off the end of `argv` here.

```
for(i = 0; i < argc; i++){
    a[i] = atoi(argv[i+1]);
}
```

If I run `./test 2 3 4 5` then `argc` is 5 and `argv` goes from 0 to 4. Your `for` loop goes from 0 to 4, but you look at `argv[i+1]` which is 1 to 5.

It's better to have your `for` loop be about iterating over one array or the other. In this case it's a bit easier to think of it as iterating over `argv` starting at 1, using `argc` for the bounds, and using `i` as the index to `argv`.

```
for(i = 1; i < argc; i++){
    a[i-1] = atoi(argv[i]);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As far as i know, arrays need to have an exact value at compile time.
There is a workaround by using the `new` keyword.

The following code will not compile on Visual C++ Express 2010.

```
int N = argc;
int a[N];
```

Note that the same compiler will not create an array which has size zero, so that should be where your problem lies.

Comment: Variable length arrays (VLA) are a C99 thing. VC++ 2010 doesn't honor C99. Later versions get better, but apparently they still don't support VLA. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zb1574zs.aspx The ISO C thing to do would be to allocate the memory with malloc. `int *a = malloc(sizeof(int) * argc)`

Comment: C doesn't have a `new` keyword.

Comment: Thank you for correcting me. I had not noticed that this question was not about C++